# Angular 2 Handle data Asynchronous

Tags: asynchronous, angular

I´m quite new to Angular 2 and I have a little Problem:
I load data from a service asynrochnus.
The data arrives in my component and i can handle with it.
Here i save the data in a local variable.

Here´s the code from the component:

```
export class ConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {

    private tab: string = 'general';
    private config = [];

    constructor(private router: Router, private variables: Variables, private apiService: ApiService) {
        if (!this.variables.getIsLoggedIn()) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getConfigService();
    }

    getConfigService() {
       this.apiService.getConfigService().
        subscribe(
            data => {
                this.config = data.settings.section;
            },
            //error => this.error = <any>error,
            error => this.variables.setFailure(error)
            //() =>  console.log('done:' + this.status)
         );
    }
```

And here´s the code in html:

```
<th>{{config[5].entry.name}}</th>
<th>{{config[5].entry.text}}</th>
```

The problem is, that on the time when the view loads, the local variable 'config' is just '[]'. So the 'config[5]' fails.
But if i do not define the local variable in the component, it fails, too.

Can someone help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should push each of elements from `data.settings.section` into your `config` and check it does exist in view;

```
//in component
data.settings.section.forEach(i => this.config.push(i));

//in html
<div *ngIf="config[5]">
     {{config[5].entry.name}}
</div>
```

I hope it helps!